# Protractor How do I Start the Selenium Server on a Jenkins Build

Tags: selenium, jenkins, protractor

**Some Background**

I've been reading up about Protractor Tests running on a Jenkins Server. I'm still a little confused as to how you can start the selenium server on a Jenkins Build. Since you need to first run the following 2 commands

```
webdriver-manager update
webdriver-manager start
```

and then you need to run the appropriate protractor command

```
protractor conf.js
```

**The Problem**

Once you've run the first 2 commands, you essentially need to leave that command window open for the server to continue to run, in such a case how are you able to call the protractor command? since you need the original command line to keep running

I was hoping someone has found a clean way of doing this. Maybe a pre-requisite script that runs? or somehow being able to kick off multiple command lines on the server?

I was also looking for a way you could also quit the command Selenium Server Command Prompt when the tests are finished executing, this would make the whole process a lot more cleaner aswell.

Answer (score 3):

If you remove the `seleniumAddress` from your protractor `conf.js`, protractor will start the selenium automatically. Example:

**With the `seleniumAddress` on the `conf.js`:**

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: [ 'spec.js' ]
};
```

**Removing the `seleniumAddress` on the `conf.js`:**

```
exports.config = {
  specs: [ 'spec.js' ]
};
```

Now, using the `protractor conf.js`, protractor will start the selenium server automatically as you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can archive your goal with npm packages: [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) and [delay-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/delay-cli).

Add them as dependencies.

```
// package.json

"scripts": [
   "wstart": "webdriver-manager update && webdriver-manager start",
   "test": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm run wstart\" \"delay 10 && protractor conf.js\""
]
```

execute `npm run test`