# how to start webdriver manager through jenkins

Tags: jenkins, npm, protractor

I am trying to start the webdriver manager and run my script through jenkins. I tried adding below two commands

npm run webdriver-manager-start
npm run local-web

but jenkins gets stuck after starting the webdriver. (Webdrivevr is up and running on port 4444 and keeps showing the loader.)Jenkins is not able to run the next command.
i also tried writing a windows batch file and running it through jenkins but same this is happening.

I always have to start the webdriver manager through npm and then run my test cases through jenkins in order to do it thorugh jenkins. Can anyone help?

Comment: Use `directConnect` instead.That or you need to implement a service that will run the selenium server in the background.

Comment: can you please explain. I am new to jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

If you execute all the mentioned commands in your `cmd` then you will see that the once you run `webdriver-manager start` command you essentially need to leave that command window open for the server to continue to run, in such a case how are you able to call the protractor command? since you need the original command line to keep running.

So, for this, you can use `directConnect = true` in the `protractorConf.js`, so that you will not require the selenium server to start.

Or else create a dependency in `package.json` like this

```
// package.json

"scripts": [
   "wstart": "webdriver-manager update && webdriver-manager start",
   "test": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm run wstart\" \"delay 10 && protractor conf.js\""
]
```

And execute `npm run test` from Jenkins, it will work as you want.
Refer links inside this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52076401/1976848)

Hope this helps, please let me know.

Comment: I tried the directConnect but it doesn't work with jenkins though. It shows the same error that session not created

Comment: @TejashreeKutte, Please provide your config file and provide step by step command which you're using.

Comment: export const config: Config = {
  getPageTimeout: staticData.pageTimeOut,
  allScriptsTimeout: staticData.allScriptsTimeout,
  seleniumAddress: "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub",
  directConnect: true,
  capabilities: {
    browserName: "chrome" },
  SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
  specs: [process.cwd() + "/src/features/Sanity.feature" ],
  frameworkPath: require.resolve("protractor-cucumber-framework"), 
 cucumberOpts: {
    require: [
      process.cwd() +"/dist/step_defination/"+buildConfig.stepDefination.POD5 +"/*.js",
    ]
 }
};

Comment: Above is my config. I have added the directConnect:true. it runs fine when i do it though npm. But it does not work though jenkins

Comment: Remove seleniumAddress: "localhost:4444/wd/hub"